# List text won't align with image

Tags: html, css

I have these images that reside in every list element in my unordered list:

```
<ul class="bot">
    <li>
       <img src="images/crime.png" class="pil-img">
       <a href="#">Fire</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I wish to align the text in the list item as shown in the image
Now, I've given the following style to the `<img />` element in my list item:

```
.pil-img {
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin: 4px 0px 0px 15px;
}
```

and to the `<a />` tag

```
.bot li a { margin-top: -5px; }
```

[image]

but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?
Cheers

Comment: Your image doens't really correspond with what you are asking, can you maybe make a jsfiddle?

Comment: You mean align them vertically?

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Some text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some text</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li {
  background: url(image.png) no-repeat 100% 0;
  line-height: HEIGHT OF IMAGE (i.e. 100px);
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
}
```

There's a start. I would need to know the dimensions of your image to help you more.

If you need to have 2 images (star + cross/check) then you should add 1 bg to the `<li>` and another to `<a>`. That should start you off on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you in your overall context.

HTML

```
<ul class="bot">
    <li>
       <div class="div_class"><img src="images/crime.png" class="pil-img"></div>
       <div class="div_class"><a href="#">Fire</a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.div_class {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You can tweak the `pil-img` class as desired.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MJnWh/).